# WinRT Create File at Customized Path

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, c++-cx

I am writing some code to create a file from a Windows 8 app in an standard way, the code looks like below:

```
using namespace Windows::Storage;

StorageFolder^ folder = KnownFolders::DocumentsLibrary;
String ^filename = ref new String(L"file.txt");

auto createFile = folder->CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting);
concurrency::create_task(createFile).wait;
```

Now instead of using `DocumentsLibrary`, I want to write thid file to an customized file path, like:

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\ExampleApp\ExampleFolder`

How should I change the code to be able to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinRT can only access a few folders. You have a few standard libraries like Pictures, Music, etc (Documents requires elevated rights) and you have the application data folders that you can find under `\AppData\Local\Packages\yourpackage`.

Inside of this package folder you have two main folders to store data: `LocalState` and `RoamingState`. As the names convey: the former is to store data locally while the latter will synchronize its contents whenever possible (according to the rules you define).

You can access these folders using the C++ equivalent of `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` and `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder`.

What you can do though is request explicit access through a `FilePicker` but this will prompt the user a window where he should target the directory himself.

Comment: Thank you, and one more follow up question on this. What if I want to specify a sub-folder in the Local Folder? How should I construct the StorageFolder^ ?

Comment: You can make your own folders in the local folder using the code you have in your question: `ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->CreateFolderAsync("myfolder");` (I don't know C++ so it might not be the exact syntax)